# how to get subplots in 5*5 dimension

Tags: python, matplotlib

[I am looking for an Output like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OcHuM.png)I want to plot the data from a CSV file which have 12 Million rows and 16 columns. I want to plot between the first column(x-axis) and the remaining columns in every iteration.

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

data=pd.read_csv('measurement.csv',header=None)

for x in range(1,len(data.columns)):  
    ax=plt.subplot(5,5,x)
    plt.plot(data[0],data[x])
 plt.show()
```

Comment: can you include i sample of your data and a bit more explanation of what you want? Maybe even include an attempt to get the output you desire, if its not too much trouble...

Comment: I added an Image how I want the Output to be

Comment: You forgot to tell what problem you face. Note that there is an empty space too much before `plt.show()`. Else the code looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

move the plt.show() out of the loop, this is blocking and thus will not allow you to build up the entire figure.

Since I do not have your dataset this code cannot be tested exactly like you implement it but I think the rest is fine. (except that 16 columns will not give you a 5*5 grid)

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = np.random.random((16, 100))
for x in range(1, data.shape[0]):
    ax = plt.subplot(5, 5, x)
    plt.plot(data[0], data[x])

plt.show()
```

This is done with some random numpy data but should work with your dataset as well.

Comment: I am getting the following error.Exceeded cell block limit (set 'agg.path.chunksize' rcparam)

<Figure size 432x288 with 15 Axes>

Comment: This could be due to a limit on the amount of point you can plot in a single image, : https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/5907